# Lucee CFCs throw an XML error

Tags: xml, apache2, railo, lucee

I'm running Lucee 4.5.1.023 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. When I create a .cfm file and do an cfoutput or a cfdump, the output is as you'd expect. However, when I use a function within a CFC and have the function set to output="true" and do a cfoutput or cfdump, the result is the following "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed".

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="test" access="remote" output="true">
        <cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The XML Parsing Error is returned if output="false" and if there is no output generated at all. e.g.

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="test" access="remote" output="false">
        <cfset var a = 1>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know this is a rather old post, but it happened to me today.  To resolve the error I added a ` cfheader( name="Content-Type", value="text/html" ); ` in the function before the output.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a lucee installed but your function access method is set to "remote".

My assumption is that the lucee server is accordingly trying to return a response in XML format. Outputting anything within your function call will be inserted into the generated XML stream which will break the XML.

For debugging you could set the access method to "public" and output to true. That will let you debug the code. Infact unless you plan to expose your CFCs as a service you probably will be best not to use "remote".

You can also call your method like so from within a standard cfml page. You could setup such a page explicitly for debugging the component during development.

```
<cfset myComponent = createObject("mycomponent")>

<cfoutput>
    <cfset myComponent.myMethod()><!---  --->
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Switching to "public" results in the following error "component [test] has no remote function with name [test]". In the past (ColdFusion or Railo), exposing functions as "remote" allowed them to be hit by a web browser or via an ajax call.

Comment: so as is suspected the CFC is being called as a web service.

if you post the way you are trying to call the method, I could most likely gibe you an example on how to call the method for testing purposes.

Comment: That would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I have added little bit of code to my existing answer to show you how you could test your component. Create new cfml page and then use the cod snippet to call the component. Doing it this way will tell the server that you want just HTML as a response.